# Updating attribute based on time - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I building a rewards system for a coffee shop. Basically a customer can sign up for a year subscription. Right now when they sign up the `active` attribute is toggled to true. I'm trying to write a method that will toggle the attribute to false after a year passes. I have a method right now that I want to use but I don't know where to use it at? I also have a failing test. I'll show my current code for clarity.

### Controller:

```
  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new(subscriber_params)
    if @subscriber.save
      @subscriber.touch(:subscription_date)
      @subscriber.update(active: true)
      SubscriberMailer.welcome_subscriber(@subscriber).deliver_now
      flash[:notice] = "Subscriber Has Been Successfully Created"
      redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

### Model method I want to use:

```
    def not_active(subscriber)
    if subscription_date < 1.year.ago
      self.update(active: false)
    end
  end
```

### Failing Test:

```
  it "sets active to false after a year" do
    subscriber = create(:subscriber)
    subscriber.update(active: true)

    Time.now + 366.days

    expect(subscriber.active).to eq(false)
  end
```

So hopefully this idea is clear. I just want to update to active: false if the user was created over a year ago.

Comment: You haven't run the `not_active` function in your test, so the `active` attribute hasn't been updated. You will probably want to run that on some scheduled basis (e.g. daily) with something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

Comment: The expression `Time.now + 366.days` does not change the current time. Moreover, the `not_active` function is never called. Why do you expect it to work? My advise: 1) remove the `active` attribute. 2) Create method `def active?; subscription_date > 1.year.ago end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to this would be to use cron. There is a rubygem to interface with cron, called [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). The setup is simple and well documented.

With cron setup on your server, you would create some kind of class method that would iterate through `Subscribers`, calling the `not_active` method.

Btw, if the `not_active` method is defined within your `Subscriber` model, you won't need to pass subscriber as an argument, as self will be implicitly set to the subscriber.

The code would end up looking something like:

in subscriber.rb

```
def self.set_subscribers_to_inactive
  find_each(active: false) do |subscriber|
    subscriber.inactive!
  end
end

def inactive!
  update(active: false) if subscription_date < 1.year.ago
end
```

in schedule.rb

```
every 1.day do
  runner "Subscriber.set_subscribers_to_inactive"
end
```

As mentioned, your test is not actually calling the `not_active` method.

```
it "sets active to false after a year" do
  last_year = DateTime.current - 366.days
  subscriber = create(:subscriber, active: true, subscription_date: last_year)
  subscriber.inactive!

  expect(subscriber.active).to eq false
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You must run the `not_active` method in order for the method to have an effect. The method has no way of knowing what the date is today and updating a subscriber unless it is actually run. I agree with matt that you would likely run this method in a [sidekiq job](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) daily on on all of your subscribers who subscribed a year or longer ago and are active (You can write a scope for this). This way you can call the `not_active` method and set each subscriber's active appropriately, or write it as a Subscriber class method and apply it to the results of your scope. In the case of testing the `not_active` method itself all you need to do is call it and test the result. Its also not clear to me why the `not_active` method takes a subscriber as an arg, it seems like it would make more sense to just call it from a subscriber instance. Is this not whats already happening? I would personally call this method something like `deactivate!`, as its making changes. `not_active` kind of sounds like it would return a boolean or an inactive subscriber. I would also recommend using update! instead of update in `not_active`. [update!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) will raise an error if the update fails. Adding to time.now does actually change the time. You can use [rspec mocks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update-21) to fake the current time if you need to. In any case here is what your `not_active` test might look like:

```
it "sets active to false after a year" do
    subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscription_date: (1.year.ago - 1.day), active: true)

    #changed not_active to deactivate, called from instance instead of passing in subscriber
    subscriber.deactivate!

    expect(subscriber.active?).to eq(false)
end
```

You can also write a test for the other case

```
it "does not deactivate a recent subscriber" do
    subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscription_date: Date.today, active: true)

    subscriber.deactivate!

    expect(subscriber.active?).to eq(true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `cron` and `whenever` gem which works on top of `cron`. You just need to write a super simple script which will extract data from DB and update it.

Another way to solve your problem is not to update anything. You only need `*_expires_at` column and check if its value less than current date.

It is pretty agile method, because by using `activation_expires_at` column you are able to implement `#active?` method and `.active` scope to select only users with active subscriptions.